# kafka streams in golang

Tags: go, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to use golang to create a kafka stream client in Go.  From what I have seen this is only possible if using a Java Client.  I did a bit of searching and found a few other third party libraries but nothing official.  Also from my limited understanding I think streams is syntactic sugar over the standard consumers ? is this correct ?

Comment: Any updates regarding this?

Comment: I think that kafka streams library can be written ground up in go and it will hugely benefit providing a streaming solution for non-jvm based applications both on prem and in the cloud. Hopefully, confluent will think in this direction.

Comment: There is a goka https://github.com/lovoo/goka but not sure how mature this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your this particular question,

> Also from my limited understanding I think streams is syntactic sugar
> over the standard consumers ? is this correct?

When implementing **asynchronous microservices**, we could use **producer** and **consumer** APIs but these APIs are too low level, they were good to understand how to use **Kafka**, but if we want to implement more complex applications, they might be too low level. Also, when we develop **event‑driven applications**, we might need to implement **multistage** processing when we would connect multiple stages. At each stage, we will read events from **Kafka**, process them, and write to output topics. Again, using producer and consumer APIs would be quite a lot of work. And one of the more high‑level solutions we can use is called [Kafka Streams](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/index.html). **Kafka Streams** is a very versatile library, it supports **stateless** stream processing and it also supports **stateful** processing.

**Note:** And if you have the option of working with a language other than **Go**, I would highly recommend working with **Java** for **Kafka Streams**. Just to mention here we have been working with Kafka Streams using Java for the last two years and we have felt Kafka Streams is more of a Java library than a distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

When using standard Consumer and Producer directly, it lacks support for such as the following:

- stream transformation (aggregation and etc.)
- fault-tolerant state in local (kstreams uses RocksDB)

Goka [https://github.com/lovoo/goka] is now a relatively active project for Kafka Streams golang support.